# Line defined by two geographical points crossing circle area with defined radius

Tags: algorithm, line

I'm trying to calculate the number of lines crossing a circle area defined by a center and radius.

[image]

This [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-collision-detection) didn't work for me, it returns too many lines.

Is there any other approach which could help my to calculate the lines crossing the circle?

Comment: Could you explain what role the "two geographical points" might play in this calculation? It *looks* like points have nothing to do with it and all you want to do is analyze *line segments* appearing within a circular area. And by "amount of lines" do you need a count, a total length, or something else?  (The total length question has been asked many times on this site.)

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The shapely library can help you. There is no real circle, but a polygon can substitute it. The minimum solution can be:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Linestring
c = Point(0, 0).buffer(10)    # circle approximation from 64 points
l = LineString([(-11, -11), (11, 30)])  # line from two points
c.intersects(l)  # returns True
l1 = LineString([(-1, -1), (1, 3)])     # another line
c.intersects(l1) # returns True
l2 = LineString([(-11, -20), (11, -30)])     # another line
c.intersects(l2) # returns False
```